# Eclipse Arduino makefile,subdir.mk Error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, arduino-uno

I've intsalled Eclipse and added Arduino plugin after when ı created new arduino sketch I faced to these errors.How Can ı fix these errors.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is "Cygwin"

To install Cygwin:

From https://cygwin.com/install.html click setup.exe according to your computer’s version(32/64

bit)When it downloaded,click setup.exe and follow the steps.

1)Click Next

2)Install from internet

3)Determine the root directory for Cygwin

4)Choose the Install for All Users(Recommended)

5)Choose the right internet settings for you->Direct Connection

6)Choose A Download Site

7)Select packages ->Download all things under Base Default ->Search gcc and make,download all you find.

Set path in Windows on Preference Eclipse.

Find where Cygwin placed and copy the address.Go to  Windows Control Panel->System and Security->System->Advanced 
System settings->Environment Variables->System Variables->Path add a semicolon(;) and paste the address to here.

[image]

After Cygwin’s path adjustment ended, Here are the path on my computer:

AVR-GCC: C:\Programs\arduino-1.6.5-r2\hardware\tools\avr\bin

GNU make: C:\cygwin64\bin

AVR Header Files: C:\Programs\arduino-1.6.5-r2\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include

AVRDude: C:\Programs\arduino-1.6.5-r2\hardware\tools\avr\bin

These steps will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
On the IDE go to Windows->Preferences, then expand the Arduino tab and select Platforms and Boards. Then select all the items in package_esp8266com_index.json and install all the missing packages.

After that it compiled with no issues. 
Let me know if it helped you too.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the make.exe installed with ac6 tools was the cause .  Replaced  with make.exe installed with gnu tools download problem fixed